# Inverter charger doesn't have EQUALIZATION feature for charging battery. What will be impact on battery life and backup?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, inverter

What if an inverter charger doesn't have an EQUALIZATION feature? How will that affect battery life and performance?

[image]

I have such inverter charger where the BULK and FLOAT features are available, but it is **missing the EQUALIZATION** feature. I'm using **lead-acid batteries**.

> look at my inverter setting panel
> [image]

Can you tell me about this issue? **What will be the impact on the performance and backup time of battery life?**

Comment: What kind of batteries are you using?

Comment: Why not add a link to the user manual?

Comment: Does the manufacturer of the battery recommend equalization? Some battery types are usually not equalized.

Comment: An "inverter" is usually a device that does the opposite of what a charger does, i.e. convert DC from a battery to a higher AC voltage (thereby discharging it). I assume your question is about a charger or a device that can charge as well as invert. Again, a link to the actual device would help.

Comment: @StarCat Giving the OP the benefit of the doubt I am sure it is an inverter charger, which is a very common product.

Comment: @mkeith im using lead-acid battery.
battery user manual : https://daewoobattery.com/battery-care/

Comment: @Transistor - actually inverter is a third party that doesn't have a user manual and no online website, this is I came to know after buying an inverter. but I got CD with it and on that CD there was software for this. 
look this image https://tinyurl.com/yaoovycx

in that setting panel, there is no option for the Equlization.

Comment: please come to the main point, what will impact on battery life and performance without EQUALIZATION ?

Comment: Where have you heard the equalisation is required? What do you think equalisation is? For what battery chemistries? What do you think it would do for lead acid?

Comment: The batteries will last longer if you equalize them. If you don't equalize them, they will probably still last at least two years (assuming you don't over-charge them or over-discharge them). There are a lot of variables, though, like if you keep the batteries in a warm place they won't last as long. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

The batteries you've linked are two-terminal 12V lead-acid types. These consist of six series-connected cells internally - with no means to balance (or equalize) them. It doesn't matter if you add more series cells; the charging current will be the same through all cells and the overall situation for each cell won't be any different to the single-battery case. However, you probably shouldn't mix old and new batteries as this might cause excessive stress on the lowest-capacity (oldest) battery in the circuit.

TL;DR these batteries will be fine without equalization.